# Force exerted by one current carrying wire loop on another

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current, electromagnetic-induction

I am training for my physics exam and I stumbled upon this question:

> We are given two current carrying wire loops with radii $R_1 \ll R_2 $
> who are coaxial. The distance between them is $X$. Both loops have the
> same linear resistance density $\rho \left(\frac{\Omega}{m}\right)$.
>
> 1. When a current $I_{2}\left(t\right)$ is flowing through the smaller loop, what is the electromotive force in the large loop?
> 2. What is the force loop 1 exerts on loop 2?

How can one solve this question?

I think in 1 we should use Inductance reciprocity, and using the fact that $\mathscr{E}=-\frac{d \Phi}{d t}$, but in 2 I'm quite lost. I'm not sure how to calculate the magnetic force here, and I also think we have an electric field as well, since change in the magnetic field results in the change of the electric field, but I don't know how to calculate that, and if I should also take into account the electric and magnetic field caused by the other ring as well (self-induction and so on).

After finding $E,B$, though, We can use the Lorenz force and find the needed force, or use $E,B$ to calculate the potential energy $U$ and use the relation $F=-\frac{dU}{dt}$ (although here it feels redundant and using the Lorenz force feels much better)

Comment: you speak only of a current in the inner loop. than you have no force on the outer loop. the force between the loops depends on the  relative direction of the current.

Comment: @trula why is there no force on the outer loop? both loop affect each other, and themselves, and the current changes because of that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force between parallel current carrying loops](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/572395/force-between-parallel-current-carrying-loops)