# Derivation of the force between two current loops

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electricity, magnetic-moment, magnetostatics

Could you explain me how to derive the force between two current loops carrying currents $I_1$ and $I_2$, written as a double loop integral:
$$
\vec{F}_2 = \frac{\mu_0}{4 \pi}  \oint \oint \frac{I_2  d \vec{\ell}_2 \times I_1 d \vec{\ell}_1 \times\vec{\mathscr{r}} \,}{\mathscr{r}^3}
$$

Comment: The first few lines of the second answer in this [post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/572395/force-between-parallel-current-carrying-loops) read the recipe that you need to derive the equation above.

Comment: @franz speaking second answer Isn't really helpful. Cause  another post may get more votes in future even now also. So you should always remark which post you are talking about.... Anyway, were you talking about this - https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/572669/315444

Comment: exactly @BillyIstiak